# How to work with ES Modules in the browser?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

This is my folder structure:

[image]

These are my files:

```
/* index.html */
<body>
  <h1>Modules</h1>
  <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
// index.js
import fruits from "./fruits";

console.log(fruits);

// fruits.js
const arr = ["Mango", "Appple", "Banana", "Guava"];

export default arr;
```

Everything looks fine to me, still I am getting the error: **`net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not have Node.js style module resolution. You have to specify the exact URL to the module.

```
import fruits from "./fruits.js";
```

---

And remove this:

> ```
> <script type="module" src="./fruits.js"></script>
> ```

… it doesn't *do* anything. It's only useful when you import it somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Try
import fruits from "./fruits.js";

Instead of
import fruits from "./fruits";